# OpenERP module for school management

Tags: module, odoo

Does anyone have any idea about a good school management module of OpenERP ?

Also, I want to create a very basic application in OpenERP that would just display a form to get user data, like name, email, add. store it and then show the report when required.
Please assist how should i get started with.

Answer (score 3):

https://launchpad.net/school-base-openerp-module but it doesnt work on openerp 6.0.1+ . Sometime ago as a partime-money-making-project I made a school module based on openerp after considering requirements of dozen of Indian schools/collegs and provided them with the solution. If enough interest is there, I can maybe opensource it on github.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore app.openerp.com for the same, I have done some for you you can click following link [OE School MOdules](http://apps.openerp.com/?filter=%7B%22order_by%22%3a%20%22click_counter%20desc%22%7D&text_search=school), but yes this module may very as per their version so you may need to port the code as per your OE Version, Else enjoy freedom of OpenSource ;)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Training modules on openerp apps...

http://v6apps.openerp.com/addon/4466?filter=%7B%22order_by%22%3A+%22click_counter+desc%22%2C+%22text_search%22%3A+%22training%22%7D&page=0

They were updated some time ago to work with v6.1